# Arm exercises: when to alternate arms?

Tags: exercise, tendinopathy, prevention, physiotherapy

I need to do three arm exercises A, B, and C. For each exercise, I perform 2 series of 10 repetitions. I can only work with one arm at a time. Is  there any scientific study that looked at which of the following sequence is preferable to maximize muscle gain while minimizing the risk of injury (especially, tendinopathy)?

- Do all exercises A, B, and C with left arm. Then, do all exercises A, B, and C with the right arm.
- Alternate arm between each exercise, i.e.: Do the two series of exercise A with the left arm. Then, do two series of exercise A with the right arm. Do the same for exercises B and C.
- Alternate arm between each series, i.e.:  Do the first series of exercise A with the left arm. Then, do the first series of exercise A with the right arm. Then, do the second series of exercise A with the left arm. Then, do second first series of exercise A with the right arm. Do the same for exercises B and C.

Comment: Please do not cross post a question just because it was closed on another site. Unless the close reason is "Belongs on another site", in which case the moderators will migrate it, it is just as likely to be closed for the same reasons as the original site closed it.

Comment: I reopened it, however you may run into the same problems, in that there just may not be any studies specifically addressing this, especially from a tendinopathy viewpoint.

Comment: @JohnP Sounds good, thanks, yes I am not very optimistic, but who knows.

Comment: Depends on what trajectory you are, if you are on a plateau, you need to shock the muscles as [Arnold Schwarzenegger explains here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9zCgPtsups) so in that case you would need to do all the exercises with one arm.